# Catch click in generated HTML with mouseover

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to catch a click on a field that has been generated by innerHtml.
this field has a mouseover handler.

In the sample below a click on the div (de)selects a variable.
the generated HTML is done by javascript, what generates a text in normal font and the selected state in bold.

The strange part is, that the click is handled when I click on the 'normal' text, but a click on the bold text isn't handled.
When I remove the mouseover, the click works as expected on both parts, but I want to keep the mouseover...
Why isn't the click working inside the bold text with the mouseover?

Example.html:

```
<div (click)="selected = !selected" (mouseover)="mouseover()">
  <span [innerHtml]="getBody()"></span>
</div>
```

Example.ts:

```
...
  selected = false;
...
  getBody() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`hello / <b>${this.selected}</b>`);
  }
  mouseover() {
    // dummy
  }
```

example in stackblitz: https://angular-u91nh6.stackblitz.io

Comment: can you create a stackblitz with an example of what you've done and what you are trying to do ?

Comment: thank you, example has been added

Comment: can you give us the link WITH the code ;) ?

Comment: Why can't you just add the code inside the span adding (click) on the tag you want?

Comment: lol, maybe I've should have saved it first :-)

Comment: @JacopoSciampi inside the getBody function I have more complex code that generates the HTML, but for this example I've simplified it.

Comment: Ok that's clear, but I still don't get it why are you adding this code dinamically by an innerHTML. Why aren't you putting all this code inside the span tag?

Comment: When I try to change it to <span>{{getBody()}}</span>, I get the message 'SafeValue must use [property]=binding', so I don't know if that will work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason , but if you just return your string in the component, it work as you want.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgsrp9

EDIT : and like this ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4kmrt

EDIT EDIT :

So you can change your value with a replace of a string, it will insert the change inside the dom, if you want to keep the blue color, you can change your view encapsulation.

When your application is running in production mode, the HTML and classes are generated by angular, so it doesn't keep the inside information  for your style.

you can avoid this problem by changing your encapsulation strategy

here is the stackblitz updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnky6k

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it indeed does work in my example, but unfortionally in my real app I see texts like 'H<b style="color:blue">ell</b>o world' inside the html.So I guess that is not the solution for me.

Comment: Yes, this is definitly an improvement :-)
Just one note is that the given style (color:blue) isn't visible anymore,
but this is an acceptable solution.
(changed stackbliz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u91nh6)